# Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) error on Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I try to upgrade `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads` library to 20.0.0 from 19.0.0. and I'm getting this error:

[Targeting S+ Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZiEw.png)

App versions:

[my app versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqgLi.png)

Gradlle: 4.2.2
Kotlin: 1.6.10

I tried to upgrade other libraries which use same library to avoid class dubliced but now throwed it.
I tried some solutions but didn't work for me

Comment: can you share your code

Comment: Check [admob release notes](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rel-notes) , either use `20.5.0 or higher`  version or add `work-runtime` library as mentioned in `20.4.0` release notes